# Use SMS feature of Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, sms, azure-ad-b2c

We have a requirement wherein we need to send SMS using AAD B2C. We are not using AAD B2C pages. We understand that by using custom policies we can use the SMS feature but how to return the control to the application after SMS generation and validation is done by AAD B2C. The UI is rendered by application.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AAD B2C does not provide capabilities to use SMS via an API. You must use the AAD B2C pages to perform MFA or Email verification.